# Meaning of the object returned when VirtualzedList is slow to update in React Native

Tags: javascript, performance, react-native, react-redux, react-native-flatlist

I am working on making a social networking app for my university campus. I am using React Native. Right now I am using Redux to maintain my app state, React-redux to bind the state to various React components and redux-thunk to make async API calls to fetch and post data. Any data that I receive, I am normalising it before committing it to the Redux store. One major problem I am facing is that whenever I start scrolling through the "Feed" of the app I get a warning:

```
VirtualizedList: You have a large list that is slow to update - make sure your renderItem function renders components that follow React performance best practices like PureComponent, shouldComponentUpdate, etc. Object {
  "contentLength": 6298,
  "dt": 4840,
  "prevDt": 7619,
}
```

I wanted to know what do the various key-value pairs in the object above actually mean. Also, what should these values be approximately for good user experience.

Note: I am using `FlatList` to render individual posts of the feed.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

**Short overview**

- `dt` is the time between two last internal `onScroll` event fires, which is an indirect measurement of your render time;
- `prevDt` is the same measurement for one cycle beforehand;
- `contentLength` is the primary dimension (width or height) of your rendered content.

These are indirect, but good rule-of-thumb measurements of how reasonably your rendering logic is cut up. For a deeper insight, see below.

---

**`FlatList` internals**

React Native's [`FlatList`](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/flatlist) is internally backed by [`VirtualizedList`](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/virtualizedlist). The latter uses the [`onScroll`](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/scrollview#onscroll) event of its [`ScrollView`](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/scrollview) to measure performance metrics.

The main metrics, `dt` and `prevDt` measure how often the `onScroll` event fires for the given `ScrollView`. Both are measured by storing the current timestamp when the `onScroll` event fires and comparing it with the last stored value. `dt` is the current delta, `prevDt` is the delta measured in the previous event fire.

In a simplified manner, this interaction is shown below, you can view the full code [over here](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/blob/84f5ebe4f941e752ba96b4d4a75dc6c6f5faa665/Libraries/Lists/VirtualizedList.js#L1382).

```
onScroll(event) {
  const timestamp = event.timeStamp;
  const dt = timestamp - this.previousTimestamp;
  // ...
  this.previousTimestamp = timestamp;
}
```

This measures how often the Javascript side of React Native receives the event from the native side. This is an indirect but very efficient way to measure whether your list took a long time to render on the native side.

`contentLength` is the size of the rendered content, which is often directly linked to the time it takes to render said content. If your content is horizontal, it is your rendered content's height, for vertical views, it's width.

```
onScroll(event) {
  // ...
  const contentLength = event.nativeEvent.contentSize.height;
  const visibleLength = event.nativeEvent.layoutMeasurement.height;
  // ...
}
```

---

**The warning**

The described warning is thrown when all of the following conditions are met (see [original code](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/blob/84f5ebe4f941e752ba96b4d4a75dc6c6f5faa665/Libraries/Lists/VirtualizedList.js#L1417)):

- current render took more than 500ms (this means `dt > 500`);
- previous render also took more than 500ms (`prevDt > 500`);
- and the rendered content is more than five times larger than actual screen size (`contentLength > 5 * visibleLength`).

To put simply, the error is thrown when your render times are long and you're rendering a lot of content in one go. For a good user experience, one can assume the recommended values are thus below the shown values.

How to reduce those issues is out of the scope of this answer, but the thrown error gives you a number of good starting points ([`React.PureComponent`](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-api.html#reactpurecomponent), [`shouldComponentUpdate()`](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#shouldcomponentupdate) etc).

Comment: I have one more doubt. Why is it that sometimes the object value is vastly different eventhough I have not changed any piece of code

Comment: @MirajShah Your phone and/or emulator are nonideal devices so the amount of resources available to your application (memory, computing power) will vary a lot, and as such, the render times will differ as well.

Comment: Okay, thanks. If you don't mind I would like to ask one more doubt. I have been working for the last two days to get rid of this warning. I tried using PureComponent and shouldComponentUpdate but achieved little success. I would like to ask if the way I pass props to the child components makes a difference. One way is passing the props along with the `data` of FlatList. The other is simply passing post_id as a prop to child components and then using connect to bind each child to the store to retrieve info like post title, likes, etc

Comment: @MirajShah One thing to keep in mind here is that the warning values are preset static values that only serve as a guide. For example, if you use an emulator with low memory it's unlikely you will ever be able to meet the suggested values. Be sure to test your application on a real device to get a feel for how it performs. As for your props question, it's a bit large for a comment, but shortly I would pass the post id to the children and let them handle it.